# Tensorflow Dataset open several files and keep them separated

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to have a 3d dataset, each data point is in a separate csv file composed of lines and my features are in the columns
I have tried several ways of adding a list of files to a dataset

```py
files = os.listdir("path")
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
```

or

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("path/*.csv")
```

and both seem to work, but then to open the files I cannot rely on `Dataset.TextLineDataset` because it would make all of my data into one big 2d dataset

I have tried using

```py
dataset = dataset.map(parse_file)
```

and

```py
def parse_file(filename):
    data = np.genfromtxt(str(filename), delimiter=',')
    return data
```

to get it as an array but I get the error

```
OSError: Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string) not found.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT : the data looks like this, it's several files that are all in this form (no headers) :

```
1498561981000,51.89105,12.41285,0
1498562341000,51.891052,12.412848,0
1498562566000,51.891045,12.412857,0
...
```

In the end I want a 3d representation where the first dimension is the file, the second is the line and the third is the column
like

```
[
[[1498561981000,51.89105,12.41285,0],[1498562341000,51.891052,12.412848,0],[1498562566000,51.891045,12.412857,0]],  
[[1498561981000,51.89105,12.41285,0],[1498562341000,51.891052,12.412848,0],[1498562566000,51.891045,12.412857,0]]
...
]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data? i.e the first lines of your csvs (or mock data), and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I just edited with example of data (delimiter was wrong by the way but that doesn't seem to have been the issue), the data is pretty simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you run into is because you are trying to use a python/numpy function in the `map` call. For performance reasons, tf.data runs its op in graph mode, which means that every function passed to map should either be native to `tensorflow`, or wrapped in a `tf.python_func`/`tf.numpy_func`. It's really tricky when it comes to I/O operation like reading a file, where it's almost mandatory to use native `tensorflow` functions.

Here is a way to read your csv and put them in a dataset. Each element of the dataset in one csv file.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def read_csv(filepath):
    content = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
    # taking care of trailing whitespace
    content_no_trailing = tf.strings.strip(content)
    lines = tf.strings.split(content_no_trailing, sep="\n")
    values = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.strings.split(x, sep=","), lines)
    # we have to nest two calls to map_fn, one for each line, then for each columns
    float_values = tf.map_fn(
        lambda x: tf.map_fn(tf.strings.to_number, x, fn_output_signature=tf.float32),
        values,
        fn_output_signature=tf.float32,
    )
    return float_values

files = ["test1.csv", "test2.csv"] # or any way to get a list of file names
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files)
ds = list_ds.map(read_csv)
```

Writing to files `test1.csv" and test2.csv" with identical content and then looping over that dataset we see:

```
>>> for elem in ds:print(elem)
tf.Tensor(
[[1.4985620e+12 5.1891048e+01 1.2412850e+01 0.0000000e+00]
 [1.4985623e+12 5.1891052e+01 1.2412848e+01 0.0000000e+00]
 [1.4985626e+12 5.1891045e+01 1.2412857e+01 0.0000000e+00]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1.4985620e+12 5.1891048e+01 1.2412850e+01 0.0000000e+00]
 [1.4985623e+12 5.1891052e+01 1.2412848e+01 0.0000000e+00]
 [1.4985626e+12 5.1891045e+01 1.2412857e+01 0.0000000e+00]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: This seems to be what I needed indeed, the only problem left is that all my csv files have a blank line at the end and that seems to break the process of parsing the file
Any idea on how to avoid that or do I just have to change all my files to not have that ending line ? (I would prefer to avoid that solution because this is how files are written automatically when I use csv.writer.writerows)

Comment: You can use `tf.strings.strip`, I edited my answer, adding that feature.,